# Extract "10% off" or "£25 off" from string via regular expression

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, extract

I'm trying to extract part of the string, e.g. "10% off food preparation with Comet", I need the "10% off" part extracted to match with something else later.

Also sometimes string start with "10% off" and sometimes it starts with "£50 off" so it's a bit tricky.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks!
Milos

Comment: if you're screen-scraping the data from other web sites, you'll need to deal with whatever character encoding, entities and escaping they're using. the `£` in particular can be represented in a number of ways in an HTML page.

Comment: I'm not scrapping data, this is for our own website and encoding is set to UTF-8

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`(£\d+|\d+%) off` should do it, the `\d+` part means 'one or more digits'.

Comment: Works fine as well but as in other example, when pound symbol returned it looks like "�3 off".

Comment: @Milos That sounds like a separate issue to the regex then. Setting your webpage to UTF-8 could be the problem, as unfortunately PHP still has no real Unicode support. Have you tried using ISO 8859-1 and seeing if that works ?

Comment: There is another issue, sometimes there is "2.5% Off" and in such cases it returns only last digit e.g. "5% off". Any idea how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: @Milos Changing the \d parts to (?:\d|\.) instead should fix that.

Answer (score 1):

```
((?:£\d*|100%|[0-9][0-9]?%) off)
```

This regex can help you

Comment: Thanks! Almost working correctly :)... for pound symbol when returned I get "�3 off".

Answer (score 1):

Try with this one : /^(.* off)/Ui

Edit :
Or /([0-9]+. off)/Ui

Comment: This will catch any sentence that has the word off in it. It's also too greedy. In the sentence "Heading off on holiday? Get 10% off your next booking.", your RegEx would return "Heading off on holiday? Get 10%".

Comment: Not greedy, take a look at U option